# How to inject a method using Unity in all the members of an interface?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am trying to execute an authentication method on all the methods from a particular interface and I found out that it can be achieved by using the Unity framework through method injection.

I got a book about Unity but I just cannot get my head on it..can anyone provide me an easy example on how would you force a method to be executed prior to all the methods in a class using the Unity framework?

Thanks.

Comment: There's great examples in the online [developer's guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that you can copy and paste into a console application directly.  Add some comments if you have questions about anything in specific.

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        // Enable the interception extension.
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        // Registering as a singleton (container controlled) so I can run a test easily.
        //   Evaluate the lifetime that meets your needs.
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationValidator, MyAuthenticationValidator>
            (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<AuthenticationBehavior>();

        // Effectively opt-in to allow interception to occur on this type using InterfaceInterceptor.
        //   Other options exist (TransparentProxyInterceptor and VirtualMethodInterceptor), so 
        //   evaluate these options carefully.
        // And also register the authentication behavior to run on the methods of this type.
        //   There are other ways to hook up your behavior to the types (such as by attribute or by policy).
        //   Evaluate these options to find one that best meets your needs.
        container.RegisterType<IRequiresAuthentication, MyRequiresAuthentication>
            (new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<AuthenticationBehavior>());

        var authenticationValidator = container.Resolve<MyAuthenticationValidator>();
        var requiresAuthentication = container.Resolve<IRequiresAuthentication>();

        // Fake the first call as a passed authentication validation.
        authenticationValidator.IsValid = true;
        requiresAuthentication.SensitiveMethodA();

        // Fake the second call as a failed authentication validation.
        authenticationValidator.IsValid = false;
        // A SecurityException is thrown on this line before the actual method is called.
        requiresAuthentication.SensitiveMethodB();
    }
}

public interface IRequiresAuthentication
{
    void SensitiveMethodA();
    void SensitiveMethodB();
}

public class MyRequiresAuthentication : IRequiresAuthentication
{
    public void SensitiveMethodA() { /* Do something that requires authentication here. */ }
    public void SensitiveMethodB() { /* Do something that requires authentication here. */ }
}

public interface IAuthenticationValidator
{
    // Throws SecurityException if not valid.
    void Validate();
}

public class MyAuthenticationValidator : IAuthenticationValidator
{
    public MyAuthenticationValidator() { IsValid = true; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    // Throws SecurityException if not valid.
    public void Validate()
    {
        // TODO: Replace this with actual validation logic.
        if (!IsValid)
            throw new SecurityException("Authentication failed!");
    }
}

public class AuthenticationBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationValidator _validator;

    public AuthenticationBehavior(IAuthenticationValidator validator)
    {
        if (validator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("validator");
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        try
        {
            // Call the validator.
            _validator.Validate();
        }
        catch (SecurityException exception)
        {
            // Be careful to return the exception and not throw it.
            // (Throwing an exception within a behavior can cause other behaviors to be skipped.)
            return new VirtualMethodReturn(input, exception);
        }

        // Behaviors can do anything you want before the actual method call by putting logic here.

        // Call the next behavior in the chain (or the actual method if this is the last behavior in the chain).
        return getNext()(input, getNext);

        // Behaviors can do anything you want after the actual method call by putting logic here.
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        // Let registration determine which types this behavior executes on.
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public bool WillExecute
    {
        // Let registration determine when this will execute.
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```